# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for class in JUnit test in Android app module

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, junit

I'm working on a [modular Android app](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/modularizing-android-applications-9e2d18f244a0) where I have a base `:app` module and multiple dependent modules.

[image]

The `:app` module contains some shared business logic and models, including a `DisplayItem` model that gets displayed differently in each module (different sections of the UI).

All of this works fine, until I run my Unit tests in my module via the command line. When I run my tests via the Gradle wrapper, the tests in my modules fail with a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to load the `DisplayItem` class in my tests.

```
com.me.news.NewsViewModelTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

What I can't understand is why these tests run fine in Android Studio, and everything is compiling and resolving as expected, but then they fail when run from the command line. I suspect Android Studio is doing something to get these classes at runtime that isn't happening with the Gradle wrapper alone, but I can't figure out what.

Any thoughts about what is causing this error, what Android Studio may be doing, and how I could troubleshoot my Gradle build/project to fix these issues?

Comment: I have the same problem, do you managed to find a solution?

Comment: No direct solution. We ended up re-architecting our app to use Android Libraries for feature modules instead of dynamic feature modules. So now each feature library has it's own testing and build pipeline. Required abstracting shared logic into it's own core module and kind of flipped my dependency graph, but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your app **build.gradle** class. It's working fine for me

> testRuntimeOnly(files("${project.rootDir}/FEATURE_MODULE_NAME/intermediates/app_classes/nonProdDebug/classes.jar"))